# CMake build target without specifying target_include_directories

Tags: cmake

I have a project with the following file layout:

```
Project
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── app
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
└── ext
    ├──CMakeLists.txt
    └── lib
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── include
        │   └── foo.h
        └── foo.cpp
```

`foo` is a 3rd party library that I downloaded the source code of that I want to use in `main.cpp`. I can build main.cpp using a cmake file like:

```
add_executable(app main.cpp)

target_include_directories(app PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/foo/include)
target_link_libraries(app foo)
```

However I feel it should be the responsibility of the foo lib to specify what files should be included when using it. Is there a way to make this work without the target_include_directories call?

Comment: Just add `target_include_directories` with appropriate parameters for `foo` library. So these include directories will be automatically propagated to users of this library.

Comment: Wow, that was easy enough. If you post the answer I can accept it. Am I correct in assuming that in this case INTERFACE is the correct include keyword for the lib? Since main.cpp shouldn't propagate it?

Comment: If your `foo` library doesn't use `foo.h` header, then `INTERFACE` is the right keyword. But most likely `foo` library actually uses `foo.h` header, in that case `PUBLIC` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

into `extern/foo/CMakeLists.txt`.

That way the include directory will be accessible when you build `foo` library and for anyone who links with that library.

---

Note, that automatic propagation of include directory and other library properties works only when you link with the library **target**:

```
# Assuming you have 'add_library(foo)' somewhere,
# PUBLIC and INTERFACE properties of the `foo` library will be propagated
# to the 'app'.
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC foo)
```

This would work even if `add_library(foo)` is issued after `target_link_libraries` call.

Propagation won't work when link with the library **file**:

```
# Propagation won't work with a name of the library file:
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC foo.a)
# Propagation won't work with a full path to the library file:
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC /path/to/foo.a)
# If 'add_library(foo)' in inaccessible from the project,
# then linking with 'foo' means linking with a library file,
# so propagation won't work.
target_link_directories(app PUBLIC /path/to/)
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC foo)
```